# How do I enter unicode characters in eclipse?

Tags: linux, eclipse, unicode

I am running eclipse in Linux and while shift+control+U+1+1+1+1 works in other apps (where 1111 are the 4 digits of the unicode character in question) like firefox, it fails in eclipse.

I just want to add some special chars to my Java string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all else fails, just use a Unicode escape:

```
String s = "\u1111";
```

Spares you the hassle of configuring charsets for your source files as well :)

Answer (score 6):

Make the character in another program and copy it to Eclipse.

Comment: Might not be as useful as a Unicode escape when e.g. `\u00A0 (&nbsp;)`. Which can be quite irritating when comparing strings ;o)